# conditional color format every second row in a column with formattable (or any other package)

Tags: r, conditional-formatting, formattable

I have data table similar to the one below (original is 10 columns and 34 rows). I want to conditionally color format every second row base on the value in each cell. All rows with a numeric should be formated (35, 25, 20).

I also want to only have one of each doublet in the Group column while keeping both the rows they are refering to in the Obesity column. Dont know if this is possible.

```
>df
Group    Obesity       
1.a      1(ref)          
1.a      35             
2.b      0.6 (0.5,0.7)         
2.b      25              
3.c      0.7 (0.6,0.9)           
3.c      20
```

This is the code that would work on a normal numeric colum, It also works on the example data, however the colors is not correct.

```
formattable(df, list(
      Obesity = color_tile("darkorange",  "white") 

    ))
```

Reproducible data

```
 df <- data.frame(Group = c("1.a","1.a","2.b","2.b","3.c","3.c"),
                  Obesity = c("1(ref)",35,"0.6 (0.5,0.7)",25,"0.7 (0.6,0.9)",20),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: not understandable description. Please reformulate.

Comment: Tried to reformulate a bit, Also see the other comment for clarity. Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
df = data.frame(Group = c('1.a', '1.a', '2.b', '2.b', '3.c', '3.c'),
                Obesity = c('1(ref)', 35, '0.6 (0.5, 0.7)', 25, '0.7 (0.6, 0.9)', 20))
library(formattable)
formattable(df, list(area(row = seq(2, nrow(df), by=2), col = Obesity) ~ 
                       color_tile("transparent", "pink")))
```

[image]

PS: indeed, the question could be asked in a clearer way ;-)

Comment: Perfect thanks! That was the main question. The secondary unclear question was if it was possible to combine Groups with the same name. so that the two rows containing 1.a will be as one cell while the corresponding cells for  obesity is two cells.

Comment: Then you could upvote and/or accept the answer to indicate your problem is solved ;-) For the second question, sorry it remains unclear... But I think you are looking for a simple data frame manipulation, so your question could be solved by more search or asking another, specific (with details, example and expected output) question. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ;-)